# Convert multiple rows to single column

Tags: r

I am using R. I want to convert `DataFrame-1` to `DataFrame-2`

```
DataFrame-1
Variable1     Variable2
aa1           X1
aa1           Y2
aa1           Z1 
bb1           Y1
bb1           Y2
```

I want to create `DataFrame-2` which will look like this

```
Variable1     Variable2
aa1           X1, Y2, Z1
bb1           Y1, Y2
```

Comment: look like what?

Comment: The DateFrame-2 is above. Was unable to use markdown, sorry. @LeonardoSiqueira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(Var1 = c("aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "bb1", "bb1"), Var2 = c("X1", "Y2", "Z1", "Y1", "Y2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cbind(Var1 = unique(dat$Var1), 
      Var2 = sapply(unique(dat$Var1), function(x) paste0(dat$Var2[dat$Var1 == x], collapse = ", "), USE.NAMES = F))

     Var1  Var2        
[1,] "aa1" "X1, Y2, Z1"
[2,] "bb1" "Y1, Y2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Variable1) %>%
  summarise(Variable2 = paste(Variable2, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  data.frame()
df1
```

Output is:

```
  Variable1  Variable2
1       aa1 X1, Y2, Z1
2       bb1     Y1, Y2
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(Variable1 = c("aa1", "aa1", "aa1", "bb1", "bb1"
), Variable2 = c("X1", "Y2", "Z1", "Y1", "Y2")), .Names = c("Variable1", 
"Variable2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with the `cars` dataset:

```
split <- split(cars$dist, cars$speed)  

a <- list(length(split))
for (i in 1:length(split)){

  a[i] = paste(split[[i]], sep = "", collapse = ", ")}

df <- data.frame(x = labels(split), y = unlist(a))
```

The output would look like this:

```
    x                  y
1   4              2, 10
2   7              4, 22
3   8                 16
4   9                 10
5  10         18, 26, 34
6  11             17, 28
7  12     14, 20, 24, 28
8  13     26, 34, 34, 46
9  14     26, 36, 60, 80
10 15         20, 26, 54
11 16             32, 40
12 17         32, 40, 50
13 18     42, 56, 76, 84
14 19         36, 46, 68
15 20 32, 48, 52, 56, 64
16 22                 66
17 23                 54
18 24    70, 92, 93, 120
19 25                 85
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be achieved using `spread` and `unite` as:

```
library(tidyverse)
DataFrame1 %>% mutate(sl = row_number()) %>%
  spread(sl, Variable2, fill = "") %>%
  unite(col = "Variable2",-Variable1, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(Variable2 = gsub("^,+|,+$", "", Variable2))

  Variable1 Variable2
1       aa1  X1,Y2,Z1
2       bb1     Y1,Y2
```

**Data**

```
DataFrame1 <- read.table(text = "Variable1     Variable2
aa1           X1
aa1           Y2
aa1           Z1 
bb1           Y1
bb1           Y2", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```